# how do i get hierarchy of data from two different tables?

Tags: sql-server, database

I have two tables **TwitterStatus** and **twitterstatusDetails**,

I have data respectively in following manner.

[image]

Here as given in twitterstatus table 4th record with the **ts_StatusID** "587573444633427968" is parent of twitterstatus_Details table 3rd record, which having td_inReplyTostatusID value is "587573444633427968", for next record td_StatusID of recent child record is parent of twitterstatus table having that child ts_StatusID value in ts_InreplytoStatusID field, so like that it is the hierarchy, so

#### how can I get the records from both the tables based on child parent relationship?

still any concern then please ask in comment.

Thank you.

Comment: i tried it with normal queries but that couldn't help me here.

Comment: @ughai did you get my Issue?

Comment: Trying to understand the post: ts_StatusID refers to td_InreplytoStatusID and td_StatusID refers to ts_InreplytoStatusID?

Comment: @TomD'Hulster yes, exactly, if you try to compare **statusID** and **InReplyToStatusID** of both the tables then you can have better idea about it.

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand your post completely, but you can accomplish most Parent/Child queries with a left join. For example: SELECT * FROM Twitter_Status s LEFT JOIN Twitter_Details d ON d.td_InreplytoStatusID=s.ts_StatusID

Comment: no, its not like that, i need to maintain child parent relationship for all data showing in both the table.
StatusID of both of the table is ParentID of Another Data having same value as status ID in InreplyToStatusID value, i want to maintain entire child parent relationship for given data..

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your post then. Can you elaborate or see if your table structure is correct? You're trying to make a Twitter Status record be the parent of a Twitter Detail and the next Twitter Status record be a child of Twitter Detail, which doesn't seem logical to me.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/75131/discussion-between-chirag-thakar-and-tom-dhulster).

Comment: To summarise: A twitter status has a twitter detail. This twitter detail has a link to a different twitter status, which in turn links to another different twitter detail, Etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think what you are looking for is recursive CTE to get every nested level.
Hope this get you closer to your goal.

```
--REPLACE @TwitterStatus and @twitterstatus_Details with your tablename.
;WITH CteTStatus
AS
(
    SELECT h.*, d.*, 0 as lvl
    FROM  @TwitterStatus AS h
    INNER JOIN @twitterstatus_Details AS d ON h.id_StatusID = d.td_InreplytoStatusID
    WHERE ts_StatusID = '587573444633427968'--WHERE CLAUSE TO GET ROOT PARENT
    UNION ALL -- UNION TO DIG INTO CHILD's
    SELECT h.*, d.*, lvl + 1 as lvl
    FROM  @TwitterStatus AS h
    INNER JOIN @twitterstatus_Details AS d ON h.id_StatusID = d.td_InreplytoStatusID
    INNER JOIN CteTStatus AS Parent ON h.ts_InreplytoStatusID = Parent.td_StatusID
)

SELECT *
FROM CteTStatus
```

Comment: It seems good, but I want to get data based on **ts_StatusID** "587573444633427968",  when i pass this StatusID it should returns me the Entire Thread for particular Thread ts_StatusID.
I tried it via passing ts_StatusID, but Can't find Desire result.
Did you get this @AXMIM?

Comment: @Chirag Thakar I edited my answer to get data for ts_statusID "587573444633427968".  Changed the initial where clause before digging into detail.

Comment: thanks again for your valuable feedback but it returns me the data of a table **TwitterStatus** instead both tables.

Comment: @ChiragThakar
[h.* = field from table TwitterStatus]
[d.* = field from table TwitterStatus_Detail]
[lvl = How much nested is the record. (0 for root level)]

This define CTETable named "CteTStatus".
Therefore, the final "SELECT * FROM CTE" include information from both TwitterStatus and TwitterStatus_Detail in addition to column "lvl".

If anything is wrong, it is probable the "INNER JOIN" that should be changed for "LEFT JOIN" to handle "TwitterStatus" that doesn't have any "TwitterStatus_Detail".

Comment: @ChiragThakar Thanks for the offer, but I'm already busy. Have a good day.